# Hover after rotateY doesn't work

Tags: css, hover, transform

I've written a function to print a two-dimensional array and used CSS and JS to make it fancy. Now, I'm thinking about a way to print (visualize) a three-dimensional array. Experimenting for now.

In the output, a table contains the array items and table cells have hover effect to indicate the item's position in the array.

[2D array print example](http://jsfiddle.net/uazfrvt1/4/)

```
.arrayPrint { /* the table */
    font: 14px consolas, arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: default;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 20px;
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(15deg);
}
.arrayPrint td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
.arrayPrint td.index {
    background: gainsboro;
}
.arrayPrint tr.mdarr:hover td.index.row-index {
    background: HotPink;
}
.arrayPrint tr.mdarr td.index.row-index:hover {
    background: gainsboro;
}
.arrayPrint tr.mdarr td:hover:not(.index) {
    background: mistyrose;
}
.arrayPrint tr.mdarr td.col-index-hover {
    background: HotPink;
}
```

I added `rotateY` to the table to give it a depth, but that messes up the hover effect. The side that gets farther from the screen is out of reach. Hover effect doesn't work on that area. Is there a way to fix that?

**Edit**:It turns out this is Google Chrome specific problem (sigh...) FF runs it fine. Don't care about IE.

Comment: also put your hover css...

Comment: @C-linkNepal Done. You should check the fiddle example. I don't think it's a hover issue. It works fine on one side, doesn't on the other (farther) side. I think rotate and hover doesn't work well together. Hoping a solution/workaround.

Comment: @akinuri I'm not too sure what you're talking...I see no perspective, no rotation and no issues

Comment: I don't see any issues with the hover in the fiddle link, even with `rotateY(60deg)` and total of 20 columns